# Creative solution to set of nonlinear equations

Tags: number-theory, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, operations-research, binary-programming

I have a set of $N$ equations and $N$ unknown variables $x_{i}$ like $0 = x_{0}x_{1} - 1 - x_{0}x_{2}$. That's an example. Realistically the equations will be much larger. Each $x_{i} \in \{0, 1\}$. Let $X$ be the set of all $x_{i}$.

The $i^{th}$ equation takes the form $C_{i} = a_{i,0} + a_{i,1} + \ldots + a_{i,m}$. The number of terms $m$ is not necessarily the same for each equation. For each equation, $C_{i} \in \{0, 1\}$ and each term $a_{i,j}$ is either $0$, $-1$, $1$, or a product of some subset of terms from $X$. This product may also be negative, like $-x_{0}x_{2}$ in the example at the beginning.

I'm looking for some ideas to solve this system of equations (which *will* have a solution by the way). Both theoretical and practical ideas are welcome. I've tried using `sympy` and `symengine` to express the equations, but both are extremely slow to even simplify/expand these equations, let alone solve them. The size of the problem I'm dealing with is $N$ ~ 200, $m$ ~ 1,000,000. Probably I will end up coding something in C or C++, but the idea of writing a non-linear equation solver for a problem of this complexity is daunting. SAT solvers like `ortools` cannot really handle a problem of this size, so I believe I need a critical insight to simplify the problem.

Also when I say "solve" the problem, I'm really looking for *any* solution, not *all* solutions.

Comment: Can you provide any more detailed description of the linear system?  Maybe there is a better formulation.

Comment: Maybe this helps: each $C_{i}$ is a binary variable with a known value. The set of $X$ binary variables are unknown, but I know the _relationship_ between each $C_{i}$ and $X$. Namely, $C_{i}$ is the result of AND ($x_{i}\cdot x_{j}$) and NOT ($1 - x_{i}$) operations on the unknown variables, or AND and NOT operations using other AND and NOT intermediate results. This can ultimately be simplified to $C_{i} = a_{i,0} + a_{i,1} + ...$

Comment: Yes, that is helpful, but can you go back a step or two further and describe the motivating problem?

Comment: It's preimage attacks on cryptographic hash functions. Trying to come up with some creative solutions / new angles

Answer (score 1):

You can linearize any products of binary variables. See https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-binary-variables for the details.

Comment: I know about this method, but I wanted to avoid introducing inequalities